# some definition is not working in *.po file

Tags: php, html, translation, po, mo

I am using PoEdit to edit my `.po` file and making the `.mo` file. In my page I have two definitions, one is working and another is not. Can you suggest how can I make a translation file if I have to include any PHP variables in the `message.po` file?

```
<?php echo $oFontawesome->icon(array('icon'=>'comment')).' '._('Tämä toimeksianto on loppuunmaksettu.');?>

<?php echo $oFontawesome->icon(array('icon'=>'comment')).' '._('Tämä toimeksianto on loppuunmaksettu. Salasana on voimassa vielä'.' '.$_Value['date_diff'].' '.'päivää');?>
```

My `.mo` file is like

```
#: "apps/debt/view/info.php:78
msgid "Tämä toimeksianto on loppuunmaksettu."
msgstr "This case has been settled."

#: apps/debt/view/info.php:94
msgid "Tämä toimeksianto on loppuunmaksettu. Salasana on voimassa vielä"
msgstr "This case has been settled. The password will expire in"
```

The second part is not working, is it the reason I didn't included the whole line? Or because it contains a variable value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution for this problem, actually the problem was not in my *.po or *.mo file it was in my php file i was not closing the tag.
All the translate message should be inside .() tag

```
<?php echo $oFontawesome->icon(array('icon'=>'comment')).' '._('Tämä toimeksianto on loppuunmaksettu.'));?>
```

Thanks